# Создание ExpandelbeListView, где каждый элемент - ExpandelbeListView в android

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, expandablelistview

Мне нужно создать расширяющийся список, где каждый элемент внешнего списка - будет расширяющимся списком, а каждый элемент внутреннего - строкой.

Я написал 2 адаптера(скорее всего, можно и нужно было обойтись 1м,но сложно понять пока), первый - на внешний и второй на внутренний списки, соответственно.

Проблема в том, что по нажатию на элемент внешнего списка - он не расширяется, хотя, если из мэйнАктивити сделать адаптер этого типа, то он работает.

Последний лист в череде пар листа groups содержит всего 3 элемента, поэтому просто через when выбираю нужный текст для вывода в втором адаптере

Код адаптера на внешний список:

```kotlin
class ExpExpListAdapter(private val context: Context, private val groups: MutableList<Pair<String, MutableList<Pair<String, MutableList<String>>>>>): BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
    override fun getGroupCount(): Int = groups.size

    override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int = groups[groupPosition].second.size

    override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Any = groups[groupPosition].second

    override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Any = groups[groupPosition].second[childPosition].first

    override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long = groupPosition.toLong()

    override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long = childPosition.toLong()

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean = true

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int, isExpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var viewCopy = convertView
        if (viewCopy == null){
            val layoutInflater:LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            viewCopy = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,null)
        }

        val groupTitle = viewCopy?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.listTitle)
        groupTitle?.text = "Номер вагона -  ${groups[groupPosition].first}"

        return viewCopy!!
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun getChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
        var viewCopy = convertView
        if (viewCopy == null){
            val layoutInflater :LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            viewCopy = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandes,null)
        }

        val childExList = convertView?.findViewById<ExpandableListView>(R.id.exListView)
            childExList?.setAdapter(ExpListAdapter(context, groups[groupPosition].second))

        return viewCopy
    }

    override fun isChildSelectable(p0: Int, p1: Int): Boolean = true
}
```

На внутренний:

```kotlin
class ExpListAdapter(private val context: Context, private val groups:MutableList<Pair<String,MutableList<String>>>): BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
    override fun getGroupCount(): Int = groups.size

    override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int = 3

    override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Any = groups[groupPosition].second

    override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Any = groups[groupPosition].second[childPosition]

    override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long = groupPosition.toLong()

    override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long = childPosition.toLong()

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean = true

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int, isExpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var viewCopy = convertView
        if (viewCopy == null){
            val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            viewCopy = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,null)
        }
        val groupTitle = viewCopy?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.listTitle)
        groupTitle?.text = "Номер колесной пары -  ${groups[groupPosition].first}"

        return viewCopy!!
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun getChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
        var viewCopy = convertView
        if (viewCopy == null){
            val layoutInflater : LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            viewCopy = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null)
        }

        val childText= viewCopy?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.expandedListItem)

        when(childPosition){
            0->  childText?.text = "Позиция:  ${groups[groupPosition].second[childPosition]}"
            1->  childText?.text = "Пробег ПР: ${groups[groupPosition].second[childPosition]}"
            2->  childText?.text = "Общий пробег:  ${groups[groupPosition].second[childPosition]}"
        }
        return viewCopy
    }

    override fun isChildSelectable(p0: Int, p1: Int): Boolean = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было добавить собственную реализацию класса ExpandebleListView и программно задавать дочерние элементы внешнего адаптера без привязки к rootView

Код класса экспандблЛистВью -

```
class CustomExpListView(context: Context?) : ExpandableListView(context) {
    
    override fun onMeasure(width: Int, height: Int) {
        val widthMeasureSpec: Int = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(960, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
        val heightMeasureSpec: Int = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(20000, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }
}
```